# Domain Model and Contracts

Tags: oop, uml, domain-model, contract

I am modelling a DVD Rental Store:

1. A `Client` gives its `clientNumber` to the `System`.
2. The `System` checks whenever the given `clientNumber` is valid.
3. The `Client` gives the name of the `DVD` he wants to rent.
4. ...
5. ...I will later have to form an association between a new instance of `Rent DVD` class concept to the current `Client c`.

My Domain Model is something like:
[image]

I've made the Contract for the first and second operations as:

Preconditions: none

Postconditions: there exists a `Client c` such that `c.clientNumber = clientNumber`.

Now, I don't know if I should form an association between this `Client c` and the DVDStore(that I intend to use as front-end). If I don't make the association, how will I later be able to "reference" this same Client? Should I be making an association between Client and a different concept?

Thanks

Comment: You can have zero or many DVD Items for one DVD Title? Either you're doing individual inventory item tracking, or your model is a bit baroque already…

Comment: I have both individual DVD Title (for example, titanic) and DVD items(for example DVD "titanic" with a unique identifier of 230908239). Which is what you'd expect from a DVD Rental, so you can know which individual DVDs are here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one has to create an association between Client and DVDStore. Otherwise (as stated), you can't later refer to the same Client (at least without having to search for it... again!).